# Try to download multiple files from SharePoint library on Button click

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, document-library, jquery

I am trying to download multiple files from **SharePoint library** by clicking on **Download All** button.
The image is given below:[image]

How can I download all files from **SharePoint library** on a single click on **Download all** button.

Answer (score 0):

Have those files links saves into Hidden a Field(you may use split option to get array of URLs) then Inject following to the Page.

```
var urls = [
  'http://example.com/file1',
  'http://example.com/file2',
  'http://example.com/file3'
]

var interval = setInterval(download, 300, urls);

function download(urls) {
  var url = urls.pop();

  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute('href', url);
  a.setAttribute('download', '');
  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  a.click();

  if (urls.length == 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
```

Or You may utilize Iframe option as discussed below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery